# get the current view which is displayed to user and verify

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I am testing my eclipse rcp app GUI using a tool called RCPTT.

In rcptt, i want to check that a specific editor is opened or not.

right now i am using

```
get-view "Console" | get-table | is-disabled | verify-false
```

but this is wrong way to do verification.

using this code, if the console is not opened, than it click on console and  do verification.
It passed all time.

So, is there any way to

```
- first get the current view(which view is displaying currently to user.)
- then verify this view.
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont know. But try to check it's actual size on screen . Like here https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/faq/verify-control-size/

Comment: Did I understand that correctly: you want to check if the active part (editor or view) is the _Console_ view?

Comment: yes, i want to check that the current view(displayed to user) is what i expect (for ex: console or other view)

Comment: If hitting Ctrl+F7, a dialog pops up. Maybe you can use this dialog to verify if the first item (= active view) is the view you are looking for.

Comment: @howlger The view switching menu (Ctrl+F7) can not be "picked" by RCPTT's table verification.

Comment: agree with @AdamHorvath

Answer (score 1):

You can not solve it within ECL, there's no support for this.

However you can solve it with Java code. It's not easy, could be a few hours of work.

1) Write a Java method that detects the name of the active View and returns it as a String

2) Make sure it's part of your application as a static class's static method

3) Invoke it from your ECL script with the invoke-static command

4) Compare the returned value in ECL script to what you've expected

Check methods parseComposites(), viewOrEditorIsFocused() and checkNextComposite() from this tutorial:

https://openchrom.wordpress.com/2011/08/12/capture-a-snapshot-of-the-active-vieweditor-in-a-rcp-application/

You do not need all the code from it and you need some editing too.

If you make an error/typo at points 2) or 3), then RCPTT-runner will simply throw an Exception without further explanation; be careful there.